# Github-Jenkins (Windows) :SSL certificate unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: github, jenkins

we have github installed locally and I have a jenkins build server with Github extensions. When ever I try to connect to the repository , I get a

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I installed the skip-certificate-check plugin but still not able to connect to https://github.mycompany.com/repo . I can connect to https://github.com. Also my Jenkins master is on a windows machine.

From my Jenkins whenever I connect to my project , I get

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h https://github.mycompany.com/JenkinsTest.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
>   stdout:
>   stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.mycompany.com/JenkinsTest.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: Have you tried with ADD credentials in git options[as here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn0bB.jpg)